# Module declares 'MongoCLient' locally, but it is not exported

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express

I have an API that has imported the `MongoClient` module:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
```

but I am getting an error when I go to run the api saying `Module '"../../node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.ts34"' declares 'MongoClient' locally, bit it is not exported`.

I do not recall if I ever worked with the `mongodb` library, but I looked at their documentation on npm repo and I also thought perhaps I was missing an `npm install`, but I am still getting this error.

A type definition file does exist for it inside the MongoDB library and I do see `export declare class MongoClient extends TypedEventEmitter<MongoClientEvents>`, so I remain unclear as to where the error is indicated that this module is not being exported.

I think the `mongodb` library was added because someone was following the instructions here:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/

Based on this documentation:

https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/using-typescript-with-mongodb-tutorial

I changed the import statement to:

```
import * as mongoDB from 'mongodb';
```

The codebase itself looks like so:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
import * as mongoDB from 'mongodb';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import {
  EmrPatient,
  EmrDoctor,
  EmrPatientModel,
  EmrDoctorModel,
} from '../models/Emr'
import { logger } from '../logger/winston-logger'

// Move this to config
const MONGO_ATLAS_HOST: string = 'spirit-dev-abcdefg.mongodb.net'
const MONGO_LOGIN: string = 'spirit-server'
const DB_NAME: string = 'dev'

const LOGIN_PATH: string = '/auth/login'
const ACCOUNT_PATH: string = '/api/v1/account/'
let gSpyrtHome: string | null = null
let gSpyrtJwt: string | null = null

let gMongoClient = null
let gDatabase: any = null

const {
  NODE_ENV,
  USE_MONGO_ATLAS,
  V3_MONGO_PASSWD,
  SPYRT_ADMIN_EMAIL,
  SPYRT_ADMIN_PASSWORD,
} = process.env

function mongoConnectionURI(): string {
  let mongoURI: string = ''
  if (NODE_ENV === 'local' && !USE_MONGO_ATLAS) {
    mongoURI = 'mongodb://' + 'localhost:21111' + '/' + DB_NAME
  } else {
    const mongoPassword: string | undefined = V3_MONGO_PASSWD
    mongoURI = `mongodb+srv://${MONGO_LOGIN}:${mongoPassword}@${MONGO_ATLAS_HOST}/${DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  }
  return mongoURI
}

function connectToMongo(): void {
  const mongoURI: string = mongoConnectionURI()

  const options = {}

  mongoose.connect(mongoURI, options).catch((err) => {
    logger.info('Mongo connection failed!', err)
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    logger.info('Mongo error!', err)
  })

  mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    logger.info('Successfully connected to Mongo')
  })
}

async function connectToMongoDirect(): Promise<void> {
  const mongoURI: string = mongoConnectionURI()

  gMongoClient = new mongoDB.MongoClient(mongoURI)
  await gMongoClient.connect().catch((err) => {
    logger.info('Mongo Client connection error!', err)
  })
  gDatabase = await gMongoClient.db('dev')
  if (gDatabase != null) {
    logger.info('Successfully connected to Mongo Client')
  } else {
    logger.info('Cannot access Mongo Database dev!')
  }
}
```

Now it's complaining with the following:

```
Property 'MongoClient' does not exist on type 'typeof import'

gMongoClient = new mongoDB.MongoClient(mongoURI)
```

Comment: are you importing it in Node.js?

Comment: @DylanL., it's an expressJS with TypeScript API that its being imported in.

Comment: imported into what though? depending on your MongoDB driver you may need to import it a different way. It's normally imported through require `const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");` not `import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'` and where you have the node documentation listed thats what I thought you were using.

Comment: @DylanL., this is a TypeScript API, so that means we are using ES2015 way of including libraries, meaning import/export, not CommonJS module system. Are you suggesting that for this `mongodb` library, we have to use the CommonJS way of requiring it in? If you are, that would make sense, perhaps this library was not updated to work with ES2015 import/export syntax.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was thinking, I don't think MongoDB accepts the import syntax or at least I've never seen it imported that way. Let me know how it goes, if it works I'll throw up an answer for it.

Comment: I was wrong, according to [this MongoDB TypeScript doc](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/using-typescript-with-mongodb-tutorial) they import all `import * as mongoDB from "mongodb";` then connect to the `MongoClient` via `const client: mongoDB.MongoClient = new mongoDB.MongoClient(process.env.DB_CONN_STRING);` You might want to look into that link, it might have the answer you're looking for. I know MongoDB but i'm new to the TS syntax.

Comment: @DylanL., I added that import statement per the documentation you shared, but I am now getting a new error message. I added that error message and the partial codebase above.

Comment: what happens if you wrap your mongoDB with as any. `(mongoDB as any).MongoClient(mongoURI)` I know its not the best, but i'd like to see the output.

Comment: Also, I've fully replicated your file and mine is working just fine, it makes me wonder what's going on behind the scenes, such as how you're compiling your TS package. But it's definitely not the code itself, as I said mine is quite close to a copy and it's working as expected.

Comment: @DylanL., doing this: `(mongoDB as any).MongoClient(mongoURI)` worked. Could you provide an answer for what you believe was the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @DylanL., what is accomplished by doing `(mongoDB as any)`? It works, just trying to understand why.

Comment: what version of MongoDB is your package.json using? try `npm update mongodb` if you can. It's possible you're using an outdated version that requires you to install `@types/mongodb`.  Newer versions include types in their packages. I believe thats why you have to manually set `mongoDB as any` because by default it is of type `import`. I believe your Typescript error `Property 'MongoClient' does not exist on type 'typeof import'` is a Types issue. I found the workaround at [this link](https://github.com/TeamSupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader/issues/8#issuecomment-550986029)

Comment: That link might be able to provide you with more information. But first if I were you I would check to make sure Types is included in your package. if not either update mongodb or install [@types/mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongodb) Please provide me with an update, I am very interested in this issue.

Comment: Any updates? Have you checked the mongodb version?

Comment: @DylanL. Its using `mongodb` version 4.4.0, only 2 months old.

Comment: Any solution found for that? I am running into the very same problem with mongodb 4.9.1...

Comment: @fchauvel, unfortunately, I never found an answer for it and I since moved on to other projects.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the feedback. In my case, the problem seemed to be due to an incompatibility with the Typescript version. Upgrading from Typescript 4.0.2 to 4.4.4 did solve my problem .